# I want to turn icloud off on my computer but I don't want to close my account etc. I just don't want to be signed in

Tags: icloud

How can i turn it off without any significant remifications.

I have only a desktop at the moment.

Please cut to the chase don't give me a full explicanation. Just tell me how to sign out so that the sign in window stops bugging me. I don't need to be signed in right now that's all. I'm not saying i don't want an account etc.so what do i do?

When I go to system preferences the only option i've given is to sign in. As with everyone else, its driving me nuts as you can probably tell.

Thank you!

Comment: When is it asking you to sign in to iCloud? Do you have certain applications open when it's asking you to sign in? For example, I'm not signed into iCloud on my mac but I don't get a prompt unless I try to use something like the App Store where I need to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your right (please tell me otherwise),

you've downloaded iCloud on your computer running Windows, and it keeps notifying you to sign in to iCloud.

If that's the case, I've dived into it already and yeah it's very annoying.

I've personally solved the problem logging in, in fact sometimes is useful to have iCloud just right there as a widget, I mean, sometimes it's very handy.

But in other cases it's not, and so in your case you may want to completely remove iCloud on your computer and try the online version instead (which in my opinion is still far better).

---

## Solution:

So all you need to do is to go on Start > Control Panel > Uninstall a program and then look for iCloud and uninstall it from your computer.

After that you won't get any notifications anymore.

But you can still find all you need [here](https://www.icloud.com/) at the iCloud's website, which is what I'd recommend you and what I daily use.